# How To automatically select a value from a drop down list using knockoutjs?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have two dropdownlists. I want to select an address from the 1st one, which then should automatically select a country from the second dropdown based on the countrycode. I have a subscribe method which never gets triggered when selected an address. Here's what I've done so far, I'm using KnockoutJs.

`enter code here`

http://jsfiddle.net/rayabu1234/bjdwhgzp/

Comment: Have you checked the answers? Did any of them work? If yes, could you accept it please?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of subscribe try using computed method. Check the code below

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
<li>

    <select data-bind="options: $parent.Address,
                       optionsText: 'name',
                       value: state"></select>
    <select data-bind="options: Countries, value: country"></select>
 </li>
</ul>


var Item = function(name){
var self = this;

self.state = ko.observable("");
self.country = ko.observable("");
self.Countries = ko.computed(function(){
    if(self.state() == "" || self.state().Countries == undefined)
        return [];
    return self.state().Countries;
});
};

var ViewModel = function(data) {
var self = this;
self.Address = data;
self.items = ko.observableArray([new Item("First")]);
};
};

var data = [
{name: "12 ball road", Countries: [
   "UK", "Uk1", "Uk2" 
]},{name: "12 kent road", Countries: [
   "PK", "PK1", "PK2" 
]},{name: "11 withy close", Countries: [
   "DL", "DL2", "DL3" 
]},
];

 ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You had many syntax errors in your code, see the final [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjdwhgzp/6/). I rewrote your subscribe function as follows:

```
this.selectedAddress.subscribe(function(value){
    var country = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.countriesArray(), function(item) { 
        return item.CountryCode === value; 
    });
    self.selectedCountry(country);
});
```

Where `self` is a variable that holds view model. And in your markup you forgot to use `value` in options binding:

```
<select data-bind="options: Addresses, optionsText: 'Address', optionsValue: 'CountryCode', value: selectedAddress"></select>
```

And `countriesArray` should be an observableArray, not just observable. All this is in my jsfiddle mentioned above.